# swipe control can't destroy gameobject

Tags: unity

I tried to make a game where you can destroy something when you swipe or tap. However, it says `NullReferenceException` & while the swipe control actually works, the `gameobject` can't be destroyed.

```
public class checkUp : MonoBehaviour {
private Swipe swipe;
private UIManager uiManager;

private void Awake()
{
    swipe = GetComponent<Swipe>();
    uiManager = GetComponent<UIManager>();
}



// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (swipe.SwipeUp ) //NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    {
        Debug.Log("Passed!");
        uiManager.destroyed = true;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

Here's the partial code from swipe:

```
    if (swipeDelta.magnitude > 125)
    {
        //which direction?
        float x = swipeDelta.x;
        float y = swipeDelta.y;
        if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
        {
            //left or right
            if (x < 0)
                swipeLeft = true;
            else
                swipeRight = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Up or down?
            if (y < 0)
                swipeDown = true;
            else
                swipeUp = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your GameObject have a `Swipe` component?

Comment: nope, tried to added it, and it works...

Comment: I'll post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that your GameObject does not have a `Swipe` component. Try adding it and it should work.